# canvas game low performance on ipad good on iphone

Tags: javascript, xcode, ipad, cordova, canvas

(french guy scuse my english ;) )

I have finished a javascript space shoot game using a html5 full canvas after 6 month of development on chrome firefox safari and recently on mobile device using phonegap or titanium, the game has good fps on iphone simulator and on iphone 4,4s.
i have choosen not to use drawimage, not to use gradient etc, and i have read my code thousands time to make it as perfect as i can using performances tools to analyse each function on any browsers...

the game runs ok on iphone but i want it on ipad. if i compile the game on iphone using xcode and play it on ipad, with the option X2 of the ipad the game is ok but i want a fullscreen game. So, i make a canvas in 1024 replacing the 480.
all my vars has been adapted to make the gameplay run with the new size and it's ok.
but with this size (the code and all lineto, arc etc are the same juste bigger) the game has a low fps. The game is more easy beacause the gameplay is slower than on iphone..

drawing a arc for example is ok on iphone, but on a 1024 width size a simple arc is one of the function that ask the more CPU memory..

what can i do, is it impossible to make run a game using canvas witdh a big size?

i use ipad 3 1go ram... it seems that drawing arcs, and beziers forms are killing my device on 1024 size.

i know in the future using arc() will not be a problem but today with modern devices it's a problem. i have never seen a game using canvas on appstore for ipad, have you hear about it?

Thank's a lot for help or experiment

Comment: iPad 3 is actually relatively slow. Because of the retina display, and it having to push twice as many pixels to the screen, it's actually performs a little worse than an iPad 2. There are many examples of game developers disabling specially effects for ipad3 but enabling them for ipad2 and ipad4.

Comment: thank's i heard about it you confirm this detail. disabling effect for ipad3 but not on 2 is worse than i could imagine.. i thought simple (but many) rect, lineto, arc and bezier forms would run on 1024 as well as on 480 it's frustrating